# Pycharm выводит ошибку , при том что все библиотеки скаченные

Tags: python, pycharm

я новичок в такой сфере.
возникла такая проблема , что выводит ошибку кода.
все библиотеки скаченные, не могу понять в чем проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо, библиотеки вы поставили в другое окружение питона, не в то, которое выбрано в `PyCharm` (`Python 3.10 (pycharm)` справа внизу на рамке).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря куда у вас установлены библиотеки. Если вы их ставили через cmd(pip install ...), то внутри проекта в PyCharm окружение другое и в нём нет библиотек. Почитайте про окружения в python и pycharm. Чтобы решить вашу проблему, вы можете воспользоваться встроенным в pycharm GUI пакетным менеджером. Или внутри pycharm открыть терминал, он откроется с окружением проекта и внутри него через pip уже можно установить необходимые либы. Как-то так. Вообще настоятельно рекомендую изучить принцип работы пакетного менеджера python.

Comment: я пробовала и в cmd  и через терминал в самом Pycharm,но безуспешно